# How can I extend a non generic interface into a generic one?

Tags: java, generics, java-8, functional-interface

I'm trying to extends [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) so that one looks like,

```java
public interface TypedTemporalAdjuster<T extends Temporal & Comparable<? super T>> {

    T adjustInto(T temporal);
}
```

When I tried to directly extends the base interface,

```java
public interface TypedTemporalAdjuster<T extends Temporal & Comparable<? super T>>
        extends TemporalAdjuster {

    T adjustInto(T temporal);
}
```

I got an error.

> ...java: name clash: ... have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other

Is there any way to do this?

So far, I did.

```java
public interface TypedTemporalAdjuster<T extends Temporal & Comparable<? super T>> { //extends TemporalAdjuster {

    static <T extends Temporal & Comparable<? super T>> TypedTemporalAdjuster<T> of(
            final Class<T> temporalClass, final TemporalAdjuster temporalAdjuster) {
        return temporal -> temporalClass.cast(temporalAdjuster.adjustInto(temporalClass.cast(temporal)));
    }

    T adjustInto(T temporal);
}
```

Comment: I think a new interface is the way to go here, right as you did.

Comment: You can make a return type more specific, but if you make a parameter type more specific then you aren't overriding the method anymore.

Comment: Could also consider overriding inherited method, then adding a new abstract one to which the default delegates: `@Override
default Temporal adjustInto(Temporal temporal) {
 return adjustInto2((T) temporal);
}

T adjustInto2(T temporal);`. This will still be a functional interface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not override a method with more restrictive parameters, i.e. `T adjustInto(T temporal);` does not override `Temporal adjustInto(Temporal temporal);` as the parameter type `T` is more restrictive than `Temporal`. So you have two methods with the name `adjustInto` now, but due to type erasure, the parameter types are identical on the byte code level, as `T extends Temporal & Comparable<? super T>` gets erased to `Temporal`.

You could fix that by changing the declaration to

```
public interface TypedTemporalAdjuster<T extends Comparable<? super T> & Temporal>
extends TemporalAdjuster {
    T adjustInto(T temporal);
}
```

as then, the semantically identical `T extends Comparable<? super T> & Temporal` gets erased to `Comparable` instead of `Temporal`. You could also use `T extends Object & Comparable<? super T> & Temporal` which gets erased to `Object` (usually, such knowledge is only relevant when you need compatibility with pre-Generics code).

However, the fundamental problem remains, `adjustInto(T temporal);` does not override `adjustInto(Temporal temporal);` as `T` is a more restrictive parameter, so now, the interface is not a functional interface anymore, as it has two abstract methods.

A sub-interface of `TemporalAdjuster` must provide all of its operatation, including an `adjustInto` accepting any `Temporal`. So you can only do

```
public interface TypedTemporalAdjuster<T extends Temporal & Comparable<? super T>>
extends TemporalAdjuster {

    static <T extends Temporal & Comparable<? super T>> TypedTemporalAdjuster<T> of(
            final Class<T> temporalClass, final TemporalAdjuster temporalAdjuster) {
        return temporal -> temporalClass.cast(temporalAdjuster.adjustInto(temporal));
    }

    @Override T adjustInto(Temporal temporal);
}
```

However, such wrapped adjusters can not ensure correct arguments and only hide the type cast which still may fail at runtime. But it looks like you are trying to solve a non-existent problem here, as you can simply use the `with` method on the temporal, to get a type safe operation, e.g.

```
TemporalAdjuster a = TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth();

LocalDate     date1     = LocalDate.now(),     date2     = date1.with(a);
LocalDateTime dateTime1 = LocalDateTime.now(), dateTime2 = dateTime1.with(a);
ZonedDateTime zoned1    = ZonedDateTime.now(), zoned2    = zoned1.with(a);
```

That’s even more powerful than your wrapper, as when you do, e.g.

```
TemporalAdjuster a = TemporalAdjusters.ofDateAdjuster(date -> date.plusDays(1));

ZonedDateTime zoned1 = ZonedDateTime.now(), zoned2 = zoned1.with(a);
```

You define an operation only once, in terms of a `LocalDate` manipulation, while it works for other temporals by converting them on-the-fly, rather than casting.